# Strange Metapost parenthesis bug

Tags: metapost

When I compile the following Metapost file:

```
beginfig(1);
def f(expr n) =
  if n=0: 0
  else: 1
  fi;
enddef;
show f(0)+1;
endfig;
end
```

I expect to get the output 1 (since f(0) is equal to 0, f(0)+1 should be 1!). However, Metapost complains about an `Isolated expression.`

When I put the expression in parentheses: `show (f(0)+1)`, things get even stranger. The error message becomes : `Missing ')' has been inserted.` (The first quote should be a backquote, but I couldn't figure out how to escape it). Where on earth was there a mismatched parenthesis??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `def` command just expands a name into its definition, so you get literally:

```
show if 0=0: 0 else: 1;+1;
```

The semicolon in the middle is what's wrong, so let us remove it:

```
beginfig(1);
def f(expr n) =
  if n=0: 0
  else: 1
  fi
enddef;
show f(0)+1;
endfig;
end
```

This produces the correct expansion:

```
show if 0=0: 0 else: 1+1;
```

And outputs `1` as expected.

---

On a side note, I'd recommend using begingroup...endgroup for heavier macro definitions, and at least parentheses for lighter ones: for example,

```
def f = 1 + 2 enddef;
show f * 2;
```

gives `1 + 2 * 2`, which is not the same as what is probably expected:

```
def f = (1 + 2) enddef;
show f * 2;
```

which gives `(1 + 2) * 2`.